# TMDb redirect to website after user is logged in

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a website using [TMDB's api](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/sessions). When the user wants to log in he is redirected from my website to TMDb's website to do it. I'd like to redirect him to my website once he's logged in. I'm using javascript to redirect him to TMDb's website :

```
function load(){
        data_from_django = "{{ my_data }}";
        window.location.href = data_from_django;
    }
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc you included in your question tells you that you need to pass a `redirect_to` parameter

> You can also pass in a `redirect_to` param when making this call which will redirect the user once the authentication flow has been completed.

So just do that, I presume this is a get parameter in which case you'd need to add

```
?redirect_to=www./myurl/
```

to wherever you construct the authenticate url

```
https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/REQUEST_TOKEN?redirect_to=www./myurl/
```